# Is an Isometric engine used for social games like farmville, happy island, etc

Tags: flash, facebook, adobe, isometric

1) Is an isometric engine used to render the world in social games. If yes, can you guide me somewhere where I can learn how to use it.

2) Also, how are the houses, buildings, farms and other objects placed via drag and drop. Is there any tutorial for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.openspace-engine.com

Comment: actually, first non-sponsored google search result :)
Version 1.x is unlimited trial.

Comment: for as3isolib- tutorials available here- http://as3isolib.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/more-tutorials-for-as3isolib/

Answer (score 1):

AS3IsoLib is the best flash open source iso engines out there and it is easy to use. (https://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/)